# Migrate data from one big MySQL table into three smaller one

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a problem with splitting tables.

My old table has a lot of fields and I now want to split them into several small tables. I shortened the large table a bit so that you can better understand the problem I have.

Structure and data of the old large table:

Structured structure:

```
old table : alldata
+---------+------------+---------+-----------+--------------+----------+
|  ID_all | date       |  owner  |  device   |  number      | datasize |
+---------+------------+---------+-----------+--------------+----------+
|  1      | 2024-01-01 |  Max    |  Huawei   |  2024010101  |   5      |
|  2      | 2024-01-02 |  Peter  |  Apple    |  2024010102  |  10      |
|  3      | 2024-01-03 |  Ulf    |  Samsung  |  2024010103  |  20      |
|  4      | 2024-01-04 |  Simon  |  Nokia    |  2024010104  |  30      |
|  5      | 2024-01-05 |  Ralf   |  Samsung  |  2024010105  |  40      |
+---------+------------+---------+-----------+--------------+----------+
```

SQL-Code:

```
CREATE TABLE `alldata` (
  `ID_all` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL
  `owner` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `device` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `datasize` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `alldata` (`ID_all`, `date`, `owner`, `device`, `number`, `datasize`) VALUES (1, '2024-01-01', 'Max', 'Huawei', '2024010101', '5');
INSERT INTO `alldata` (`ID_all`, `date`, `owner`, `device`, `number`, `datasize`) VALUES (2, '2024-01-02', 'Peter', 'Apple', '2024010102', '10');
INSERT INTO `alldata` (`ID_all`, `date`, `owner`, `device`, `number`, `datasize`) VALUES (3, '2024-01-03', 'Ulf', 'Samsung', '2024010103', '20');
INSERT INTO `alldata` (`ID_all`, `date`, `owner`, `device`, `number`, `datasize`) VALUES (4, '2024-01-04', 'Simon', 'Nokia', '2024010104', '30');
INSERT INTO `alldata` (`ID_all`, `date`, `owner`, `device`, `number`, `datasize`) VALUES (5, '2024-01-05', 'Ralf', 'Samsung', '2024010105', '40');
ALTER TABLE `alldata` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID_all`);
ALTER TABLE `alldata` MODIFY `ID_all` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
COMMIT;
```

And this is what my new little three tables look like:

Structured structure:

```
1. newtable : workspace
+------------+------------+------------+
|workspaceID | date       | number     |
+------------+------------+------------+
|  1         | 2024-01-01 | 2024010101 |
|  2         | 2024-01-02 | 2024010102 |
|  3         | 2024-01-03 | 2024010103 |
|  4         | 2024-01-04 | 2024010104 |
|  5         | 2024-01-05 | 2024010105 |
+------------+------------+------------+

2. newtable : devices
+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|  deviceID  | workspaceID |    owner  |  device  |
+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|  1         |  1          |  Max      |  Huawei  |
|  2         |  2          |  Peter    |  Apple   |
|  3         |  3          |  Ulf      |  Samsung |
|  4         |  4          |  Simon    |  Nokia   |
|  5         |  5          |  Ralf     |  Samsung |
+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+


3. newtable : datasize
+------------+----------+-------------+------------+
| datasizeID | deviceID | workspaceID |  datasize  |
+------------+----------+-------------+------------+
|  1         |  1       |  1          |   5        |
|  2         |  2       |  2          |  10        |
|  3         |  3       |  3          |  20        |
|  4         |  4       |  4          |  30        |
|  5         |  5       |  5          |  40        |
+------------+----------+-------------+------------+
```

SQL-Code:

```
CREATE TABLE `workspace` (
  `workspaceID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE `devices` (
  `deviceID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `workspaceID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `owner` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `device` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE `datasize` (
  `datasizeID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `deviceID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `workspaceID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `datasize` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
COMMIT;
```

I now tried to import the data from the old database into the new one with the following command:

```
INSERT INTO workspace (workspaceID, date, number) SELECT ID_all, date, number FROM oldtable;
INSERT INTO devices (deviceID, workspaceID, owner, device) SELECT '',LAST_INSERT_ID(), owner, device FROM oldtable;
INSERT INTO datasize (datasizeID, deviceID, workspaceID, datasize) SELECT '', LAST_INSERT_ID(), LAST_INSERT_ID(), datasize FROM oldtable;
```

But as you can see, the only thing I know is "LAST_INSERT_ID()" but unfortunately that doesn't work.

My goal is for an old data record from the old table "alldata" to fill the new three tables and set the appropriate IDs.

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Baffled by this - there is no LAST_INSERT_ID2 in mysql and LAST_INSERT_ID is just that so I don't get why you want all entries to devices and datesize to have the same value. Please add sample data , desired outcome and table definitions as text.

Comment: Incorrect scheme. Definite datasize may refer on some workspace directly, and on another workspace via device. Remove workspaceID from datasize table.

Comment: Provide ~10 sample source rows  and desired data state for this data. See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3

Comment: @Akina: I have edited my question with the correct tables. Is it ok like this?

Comment: *Is it ok like this?* Provided link, paragraph 5, tells: "add the actual **DDL / DML statements** to your question". I.e. CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts, not the data in table form.

Comment: The size of your current table should not be a problem for anything.  Why do this split?  After the split lots of things become more complex and probably a little slower.

Comment: Hello, i updated: hopefully perfect now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source data

```
CREATE TABLE `alldata` (
  `ID_all` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `device` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `datasize` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
INSERT INTO `alldata` (`ID_all`, `date`, `owner`, `device`, `number`, `datasize`) VALUES (1, '2024-01-01', 'Max', 'Huawei', '2024010101', '5');
INSERT INTO `alldata` (`ID_all`, `date`, `owner`, `device`, `number`, `datasize`) VALUES (2, '2024-01-02', 'Peter', 'Apple', '2024010102', '10');
INSERT INTO `alldata` (`ID_all`, `date`, `owner`, `device`, `number`, `datasize`) VALUES (3, '2024-01-03', 'Ulf', 'Samsung', '2024010103', '20');
INSERT INTO `alldata` (`ID_all`, `date`, `owner`, `device`, `number`, `datasize`) VALUES (4, '2024-01-04', 'Simon', 'Nokia', '2024010104', '30');
INSERT INTO `alldata` (`ID_all`, `date`, `owner`, `device`, `number`, `datasize`) VALUES (5, '2024-01-05', 'Ralf', 'Samsung', '2024010105', '40');
SELECT * FROM alldata;
```

| ID_all | date | owner | device | number | datasize |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-01-01 | Max | Huawei | 2024010101 | 5 |
| 2 | 2024-01-02 | Peter | Apple | 2024010102 | 10 |
| 3 | 2024-01-03 | Ulf | Samsung | 2024010103 | 20 |
| 4 | 2024-01-04 | Simon | Nokia | 2024010104 | 30 |
| 5 | 2024-01-05 | Ralf | Samsung | 2024010105 | 40 |

Insert data into "upper" table

```
CREATE TABLE workspace (
  workspaceID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `date` DATE,
  `number` INT
  );
INSERT INTO workspace (`date`, `number`)
SELECT DISTINCT `date`, `number` FROM alldata;
SELECT * FROM workspace;
```

| workspaceID | date | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-01-01 | 2024010101 |
| 2 | 2024-01-02 | 2024010102 |
| 3 | 2024-01-03 | 2024010103 |
| 4 | 2024-01-04 | 2024010104 |
| 5 | 2024-01-05 | 2024010105 |

Insert data into "secondary" table

```
CREATE TABLE devices ( 
  deviceID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  workspaceID INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (workspaceID) REFERENCES workspace (workspaceID),
  `owner` varchar(500),
  device varchar(500)
  );
INSERT INTO devices (workspaceID, `owner`, device)
SELECT workspace.workspaceID, alldata.`owner`, alldata.device
FROM workspace
JOIN alldata ON workspace.`date` = alldata.`date`;
SELECT * FROM devices;
```

| deviceID | workspaceID | owner | device |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Max | Huawei |
| 2 | 2 | Peter | Apple |
| 3 | 3 | Ulf | Samsung |
| 4 | 4 | Simon | Nokia |
| 5 | 5 | Ralf | Samsung |

Insert data into "tertiary" table

```
CREATE TABLE datasize (
  datasizeID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  deviceID INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (deviceID) REFERENCES devices (deviceID),
  datasize varchar(500)
  );
INSERT INTO datasize (deviceID, datasize)
SELECT devices.deviceID, alldata.datasize
FROM workspace
JOIN alldata ON workspace.`date` = alldata.`date`
JOIN devices USING (workspaceID);
SELECT * FROM datasize;
```

| datasizeID | deviceID | datasize |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 3 | 20 |
| 4 | 4 | 30 |
| 5 | 5 | 40 |

Reconstruct source data

```
SELECT workspace.`date`, devices.`owner`, devices.device, workspace.`number`, datasize.datasize
FROM workspace
JOIN devices USING (workspaceID)
JOIN datasize USING (deviceID);
```

| date | owner | device | number | datasize |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 | Max | Huawei | 2024010101 | 5 |
| 2024-01-02 | Peter | Apple | 2024010102 | 10 |
| 2024-01-03 | Ulf | Samsung | 2024010103 | 20 |
| 2024-01-04 | Simon | Nokia | 2024010104 | 30 |
| 2024-01-05 | Ralf | Samsung | 2024010105 | 40 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mzmCIFbz)